# Git re-merge a file using another merge strategy option?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm merging two branches with common ancestor:

```
> [branch1]
git merge branch2 --no-commit
# ... did merging for several files with conflicts
git merge branch2 -srecersive -Xignore-space-at-eol -- myfile.txt  # not possible
```

And I've resolved several merge conflicts in files which I wish to keep. Now there is a file with conflicts that are because of newline chars different. How can I make git to ignore newline chars conflicts and make another file with conflicts, with option `ignore-space-at-eol` of `recursive` strategy, ie. something like that `git merge branch2 -srecursive -Xignore-space-at-eol -- myfilewithconflicts.txt`. See picture. I can undo my merging of a file (`git checkout -m myfilewithconflicts.txt`) but how I apply another strategy to this file?

[image]

Comment: Not an answer but I could resolve this by making vim to ignore white space (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ignore_white_space_in_vimdiff). And then I could merge that file.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't.  Once you are in the middle of a conflicted merge, you must either finish that merge, or abort it entirely, to start another merge.  Neither is what you want here ("finish and start a new one" can get you there, but it is convoluted and error-prone).

Git really should have a "suspend merge" tool to let you do this in a cleaner way.  It might be possible to write one, but I don't have the time to do it.

#### Why this is so (long)

Let's start with some background.  The problem at this point has been reduced to doing three-way merges on individual files—but how did we get here?

A typical Git merge—or more precisely, what I have taken to calling a *true merge*, as opposed to the not-really-a-merge "fast forward" operation that's mainly just done as if via `git checkout` or `git reset --hard`—uses three inputs.  You specify one of these inputs, the `--theirs` commit.  The other two are implicit: they are the current or `--ours` commit, and the *merge base* as computed by your *merge strategy*.  The default strategy for this kind of merge is the one you chose in both example commands, `-s recursive`.

The *goal* of this kind of merge is to combine work.  The merge base commit serves as the common starting point from which you (on your branch, `--ours`) did some work, and they (on their branch, `--theirs`) did some work, which Git should now combine.  Since you both started from the *same* commit, this makes the combining easier: Git can run a `git diff` from the merge base to your commit to see what you did, and a second `git diff` from the merge base to their commit to see what they did.

Having run these two diff commands (or the internal equivalent of them), Git can then pair up every base file with one file in your commit, and with one file in their commit.  Doing the diff and pairing the files is all done as part of the merge strategy, but it's not yet finished: this process simply reduces the problem, down to the point of now having to combine work for each group of files.

Ignoring tricky cases like new files, renamed files, and deleted files, we now have the merge strategy, for each path name *P:*

- look at the content of *P* in the merge base;
- look at the content of *P* in the `--ours` commit; and
- look at the content of *P* in the `--theirs` commit.

As a short-cut, if the content is the same in two or three out of the three versions, there's nothing to *merge* and Git can just pick the `--ours` version that's already in the index or put the `--theirs` version into the index as appropriate.

If not, though—if all three versions differ—then this particular file requires actual merging.  Git copies all three versions into the index, in slots 1, 2, and 3 which are reserved for the merge process, and calls the *low level, one-file-at-a-time* merge code.  This code merges *one file*, using *three versions*.  The three versions are those now stored in the index (we can extract all three into the work-tree ourselves later, if we like, but that's where they are).

The low-level merge code is what we think of when we think of merge conflicts.  In fact, though, if the low-level code is able to merge *without* conflicts, it goes on to *remove* the three versions from the index, *add* the merged file as a stage-zero entry instead, and proceed as if there had not been any problem.  It's only when this fails that the low-level merge writes, to the work-tree, the *conflicted merge* version of the file.  It leaves all three inputs in the index.

#### You cannot start a new merge if you have an incomplete merge

Note that in the above sequence, Git uses the index / staging-area to store the three versions of each conflicted file, and the work-tree to store the combined version when stopping.  To do so, Git must begin with a *clean* index and work-tree.  If the index and work-tree were not clean to start with, this process could destroy unsaved work.

Git therefore says "no" if you try to run `git merge` with an unresolved merge conflict in place, or an uncommitted index, or a dirty work-tree.  If you abort the existing, ongoing merge, that wipes everything out that you have done so far, and re-sets your index and work-tree so that they are clean—but that wipes out everything that you have done so far.

Your only other option is to finish the merge—mark everything resolved and commit.  But that creates a new commit on the current branch.  If you then start a second merge, the implied merge base is the commit you just made, rather than the original merge base you had during the earlier commit.  This means you must save the merge commit, but then undo it with `git reset` or equivalent.  This is the tricky and error-prone part.

#### If only we could *repeat* the low-level merge with different options

The low-level code uses most of the `-X` options, like `-X ours` or `-X theirs`, or in your case, `-X ignore-space-at-eol`.  If we had direct access to this low-level code, we could just run it ourselves.  That would allow us to add `-X ignore-space-at-eol` for one specific file that *did* have conflicts.

Unfortunately, while there *is* a `git merge-file` command, that's *not* the code that `git merge-recursive` uses (the `merge-recursive` code is in `ll-merge.c`, which implements the low level merging, not `merge-file.c` which implements `git merge-file`).  The `merge-file` command does not accept `-X` options.  It *does* take `--ours`, `--theirs`, and even `--union`.  It *calls into* code that *could* take `-X ignore-space-at-eol`, but it has no command-line option to set that.  If it did take `-X ignore-space-at-eol`, you would be able to achieve what you wanted directly.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! Read it and it was interesting to learn about how it works actually. So I think I had a way (w/o vim), I could have completed this `merge` somehow, `commit` and then `checkout head~1`  (so that the base commit as the last time) and do `merge` with my options for my file. `commit` again, `checkout` the first merge commit and put my file to current work-tree from this second merge.